# If $I$ is a bounded interval, is there a function on $I$ that is bounded and continuous but not uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $I$ be a bounded interval. Is there a function $f$, which is continuous and bounded on $I$, but it's not uniformly continuous on $I$ ?

Comment: Can $I$ be open?

Comment: Yes. I think it must be, according to the Heine-Cantor theorem

Answer (score 7):

$\sin \frac 1x$ on $(0,1]$

That function is bounded, continuous, but is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: How can you prove that the function is not uniformly continuous?